# PostgreSQL assigns foreign key automatically on the referencing side

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So I've got Table ActorInMovies, which has 3 foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE ActorInMovie(
    ID_ROLE bigserial REFERENCES Role(ID_ROLE) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ID_ACTOR bigserial REFERENCES Actor(ID_Actor) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ID_MOVIE bigserial REFERENCES Movie(ID_Movie) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT ActorInMovie_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID_ROLE));
```

I assumed that when I try to insert something like:

```
INSERT INTO ActorInMovie (ID_ROLE, ID_ACTOR) values (1,1);
```

that it would result in an error as ID_MOVIE was not specified (null I supposed).. but it automatically starts assigning indexes staring from 1.

What am I doing wrong? As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970562/postgres-and-indexes-on-foreign-keys-and-primary-keys), I thought that "PostgreSQL automatically creates indexes on primary keys and unique constraints, **but not on the referencing side of foreign key relationships.**"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a very hard time imagining a use case where a [`serial`(or `bigserial`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column references another column. It's usually the other way round: the `serial` column should go on the other end of the foreign key constraint.

I have an equally hard time imagining a design where a `movie_id` needs to be `bigint` instead of just `int`. There aren't nearly enough movies on this planet.

Also, there is a good chance, a column called `movie_id` in a table called `actor_in_movie` should be defined as `NOT NULL`.

In short: I doubt your design flies *at all*. Maybe something like:

```
CREATE TABLE actor (actor_id serial PRIMARY KEY, actor text, ...);
CREATE TABLE movie (movie_id serial PRIMARY KEY, movie text, ...);
CREATE TABLE actor_in_movie(
   role_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
  ,actor_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES actor(actor_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
  ,movie_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES movie(movie_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

A `NOT NULL` constraint is redundant, while the column is included in the primary key.

You probably want indices on `actor_id` and on `movie_id` in `actor_in_movie`.

More details:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: I think you just hit the nail on the head! I just started with databases and thought that `bigserial` is a data type and conversion to `int` was not possible. What you wrote is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Fortunately this is just scholar example, so no harm done. Thank you!

Comment: @KubaSpatny: You may be interested in this closely related answer with a lot more explanation and links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225

Answer (score 3):

This is simply [`bigserial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) working exactly as advertised.  It has nothing to do with the foreign key constraint, or with an index.

Comment: Oh. I thought bigserial would only do it if it wasn't in reference.. Thanks!