# Optimize PostgreSQL query with ORDER BY and limit 1

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following PostgreSQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE BOX (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
);

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_item;

CREATE TABLE Item (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('seq_item'),
    SENDER INTEGER REFERENCES User(id),
    RECEIVER INTEGER REFERENCES User(id),
    INFO TEXT,
    BOX_ID INTEGER REFERENCES Box(id) NOT NULL,
    ARRIVAL TIMESTAMP
);
```

Its main use case is a typical producer/consumer scenario. Different users may insert an item in the database in a particular box for a particular user and each user can retrieve the topmost(this means the oldest) item in a box that is addressed to her/him. It more or less mimics the functionality of a queue on a database level.

More precisely, the most common operations are the following:

```
INSERT INTO ITEM(SENDER, RECEIVER, INFO, BOX_ID, ARRIVAL) 
VALUES (nsid, nrid, ncontent, nqid, ntime);
```

And retrieve commands based on a combination of either `RECEIVER+SENDER` or `RECEIVER+BOX_ID`:

```
SELECT * INTO it FROM Item i WHERE (i.RECEIVER=? OR i.RECEIVER is NULL) AND 
(i.BOX_ID=?) ORDER BY ARRIVAL LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM Item i WHERE i.id=it.id;
```

and

```
SELECT * INTO it FROM Item i WHERE (i.RECEIVER=? OR i.RECEIVER is NULL) AND 
(i.SENDER=?) ORDER BY ARRIVAL LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM Item i WHERE i.id=it.id;
```

The last two snippets are packed within a stored procedure.

I was wondering how to achieve best performance given this use case and knowing that the users will insert and retrieve somewhere between `50,000` and `500,000` items (however, the database is never expected to contain more than `100,000` items at a given point)?

**EDIT**

This is the `EXPLAIN` I get with for the `SELECT` statements no indexes:

```
Limit (cost=23.07..23.07 rows=1 width=35)
   -> Sort (cost=23.07..25.07 rows=799 width=35)
      Sort Key: ARRIVAL
      -> Seq Scan on Item i (cost=0.00..19.07 rows=799 width=35)
         Filter: (((RECEIVER = 1) OR (RECEIVER IS NULL)) AND (SENDER = 1))
```

The best `EXPLAIN` I get based on my understanding is when I put an index on the time(`CREATE INDEX ind ON Item(ARRIVAL);`):

```
Limit (cost=0.42..2.88 rows=1 width=35)
   -> Index Scan using ti on Item i (cost=0.42..5899.42 rows=2397 width=35)
      Filter: (((receiver = 2) OR (RECEIVER IS NULL)) AND (SENDER = 2))
```

In all of the cases without index on `ARRIVAL` I have to sort the table which seems to my inefficient. If I try to combine an index on `ARRIVAL` and `RECEIVER/SENDER` I get the same explanation, but slightly slower.

Is it correct to assume that a single index on `ARRIVAL` is the most efficient option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding index the best way is create, test your query and analyze the EXPLAIN plan. Sometime you create the index and planer doesnt even use it. You will know when you test it.

Primary key get index by default, you need create the index for the referenced table

[Postgres and Indexes on Foreign Keys and Primary Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970562/postgres-and-indexes-on-foreign-keys-and-primary-keys)

And you may consider create composited index using the fields on your where clausules.

Take note if even index improve selects, also have an impact on insert/updates because index need to be rebuild.

But again you have to test each change and see if that improve your results.

Comment: I added two `EXPLAIN` plans based on my personal assumptions. Can you say if my reasoning is correct, since the question is more concrete?

Comment: Your seconde explain show improvement for `ti` index but still using scan filter for `Filter: (((receiver = 2) OR (RECEIVER IS NULL)) AND (SENDER = 2))` so maybe a composite index with `(ti, receiver, sender)` will be better