# How to forbid index creation of the primary_key in the Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am creation Postgres table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IN NOT EXISTS table_name
(
    entity_key BYTEA,
    name: TEXT,
    val: BYTEA,
    ts: TIMESTAMPTZ,
    PRIMARY KEY(entity_key, name)
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS table_name_ek ON table_name (entity_key);
```

The script creates two indexes:

1. Index for entity_key
2. Index for primary_key (entity_key, name)

I have a problem: For 9 * 10^9 rows the second index size is 450 GB (there are a lot of updates in the table)

I read this page [Postgres and Indexes on Foreign Keys and Primary Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970562/postgres-and-indexes-on-foreign-keys-and-primary-keys)

> PostgreSQL automatically creates an index for each unique constraint and primary key constraint to enforce uniqueness. Thus, it is not necessary to create an index explicitly for primary key columns.

```
How should I change my script to forbid  creation of the primary_key in the Postgres?
```

I mean I want to have a primary key for (entity_key, name), but I don't want to have INDEX for this key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create the index `table_name_ek`. Since the primary key index starts with the same column, `table_name_ek` is unnecessary: all it can do can also be done by the primary key index.

You cannot avoid the creation of the primary key index, because that's the way primary keys are implemented.

Comment: Thank you for the answer by I want  to forbid  creation of the primary_key index. Is it possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible.