# Script to add an index on each foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, foreign-keys

Seeing as a [foreign key does not automatically create an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836167/does-a-foreign-key-automatically-create-an-index) in SQL Server, I want to create an explicit index on every FK field in my database.  And I have over 100 tables in the schema...

So, does anyone have a ready packaged script that I could use to detect all FKs and create an index on each?

Comment: Heh, I did one on the weekend and I discarded it. It was customised to my naming convention, so I did a lot of string manipulation and selected from sys.foreign_keys with schema_name(schema_id) and object_name(parent_object_id).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I worked this out myself - here it is for everyone else's benefit...

```
select 'create index IX_'+c.name+'_'+p.name+' on '+c.name+'('+cf.name+');'
from sysforeignkeys fk join sysobjects c on fk.fkeyid=c.id
join sysobjects p on fk.rkeyid=p.id
join syscolumns cf on c.id=cf.id and cf.colid = fk.fkey
left join sysindexkeys k on k.id = cf.id and k.colid = cf.colid
where k.id is null
order by c.name
```

It doesn't work 100%, such as if you have two FKs on one table to the same primary table, but there are few enough instances of this (in my DB at least) that I could viably correct these by hand.

Comment: In my DB this generated 0 rows, where as Scott's below did generate

Answer (score 9):

Ok, here is my take on this. I added support for schemes and also check if an index exists with the current naming convention. This way as you modify your tables you can check for missing indexes.

```
   SELECT 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_' + s.NAME + '_' + o.NAME + '__' + c.NAME + ' ON ' + s.NAME + '.' + o.NAME + ' (' + c.NAME + ')'
    FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON fkc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
        AND fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.NAME = ('IX_' + s.NAME + '_' + o.NAME + '__' + c.NAME)
    WHERE i.NAME IS NULL
    ORDER BY o.NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

I modified the query to use they system views. It will also script every FK in the table not just one.

```
SELECT 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ndx_' + o.name + '__' + c.name 
   + ' ON ' + o.name + ' (' + c.name + ')'
FROM   sys.foreign_keys        fk
JOIN   sys.objects             o    ON  fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id
JOIN   sys.foreign_key_columns fkc  ON  fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
JOIN   sys.columns             c    ON  fkc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
                                AND fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
ORDER BY o.name
```

Comment: This is nice, I'll add square braquets around the names just in case someone named a column user (just happened to me).

Answer (score 2):

Seeing all of these answers is wonderful but I needed to ignore those foreign keys that already had indexes. To that end I had borrowed some code and modified it with some of the code here.

The major parts of this code really comes from:
[Identify all non indexed foreign keys](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5004/script-to-identify-all-nonindexed-foreign-keys-in-a-sql-server-database/)

```
SELECT 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ndx_' + FK.Table_Name + '__' + FK.Column_Name 
   + ' ON [' + FK.Table_Name + '] (' + FK.Column_Name + ')'
FROM (    
SELECT 
   Object_Name(a.parent_object_id) AS Table_Name
   ,b.NAME AS Column_Name
FROM 
   sys.foreign_key_columns a
   ,sys.all_columns b
   ,sys.objects c
WHERE 
   a.parent_column_id = b.column_id
   AND a.parent_object_id = b.object_id
   AND b.object_id = c.object_id
   AND c.is_ms_shipped = 0
EXCEPT

SELECT 
   Object_name(a.Object_id)
   ,b.NAME
FROM 
   sys.index_columns a
   ,sys.all_columns b
   ,sys.objects c
WHERE 
   a.object_id = b.object_id
   AND a.key_ordinal = 1
   AND a.column_id = b.column_id
   AND a.object_id = c.object_id
   AND c.is_ms_shipped = 0
)  FK
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is any more accurate but I found this while looking for similar https://encodo.com/latest/developer-blogs/create-indexes-for-all-foreign-keys-in-sql-server/ which generates a create-script similarly to some of the above, which should at least give  more options to anyone ending up here to try things.

```
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
-- Executing this script will generate a create-script for inserting indexes
-- over all tables in the database.
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
Select
'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].['
+ tab.[name]
+ ']'') AND name = N''IX_'
+ cols.[name]
+ ''') '
+ 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_'
+ cols.[name]
+ '] ON [dbo].['
+ tab.[name]
+ ']( ['
+ cols.[name]
+ '] ASC ) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]'
From sys.foreign_keys keys
Inner Join sys.foreign_key_columns keyCols
 On keys.object_id = keyCols.constraint_object_id
Inner Join sys.columns cols
 On keyCols.parent_object_id = cols.object_id
 And keyCols.parent_column_id = cols.column_id
Inner Join sys.tables tab
 On keyCols.parent_object_id = tab.object_id
Order by tab.[name], cols.[name]
```