# If Table1.ColumnA is indexed, will a foreign key Table2.ColumnA_FK be indexed as well?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I know that foreign keys are not indexed by default, but if the original reference is an index, will a FK also be an index - i.e. is indexing transitive?

Example:

- **Table1** has a non-clustered composite index on columns(A,B)
- **Table2** has two foreign keys with references to Table1.A and Table1.B

Will running a SELECT on Table2.A_FK or Table2.B_FK offer indexed performance, i.e. ~O(log[n]) instead of non-indexed O(n)? In SQL Server Management Studio, object explorer will not list these two foreign keys as an index for Table2.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836167/does-a-foreign-key-automatically-create-an-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - no.
If you want the field of table2 to also be indexed, you should explicitly index it yourself (and as you stated, this is probably a good idea)

Comment: Thank you. One thing I don't understand: why would someone want to have a non-indexed foreign key that references an indexed column (such is the case in my situation - I didn't design the database)? Wouldn't automatically creating an index on the foreign key point to the original (referenced) index anyway, i.e. no duplication etc.?

Comment: No - an index on the referencing table would index the values in that table, not the values it's pointing to. I can't however, off the top of my head, come up with a usecase where you would not want to index a column that serves as a foreign key. Perhaps if its cardinality is very low or something down those lines.

Comment: @Mureinik: well, you might want to create an index that contains not only the FK column - but also a second, third column and possibly some included columns, too, to cover some queries. You'll still have an index on your FK column (which is a good thing in general) - but maybe not *only* on your FK column