# Is it equivalent to add a foreign key to an already existent table's already existent field with already existent records than recreation?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have three `table`s: **A**, **AB** and **B**.

**A.ID** and **B.ID** are `int` `primary key`s. **AB.AID** and **AB.BID** are int and **(AID, BID)** is the `primary key` of **AB**.

I need to make sure that **AB.AID** will be a `foreign key` which will reference **A(ID)** and **AB.BID** will be a `foreign key` which will reference **B(ID)**.

If I, using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio right-click the table and click Design and after the table appears I right-click and click on Relationships and add the `foreign key`, will I have the very same result as if I would:

1. Create a temporary `table` with the same structure
2. Migrate all records from **AB** there
3. Remove all records from **AB**
4. Change the structure of **AB** to have two `foreign keys`
5. Copy the data back
6. Remove the temporary `table`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.  Note that when attempting to build a relationship between tables, it will not allow the constraint to be created if there is conflicting data like:

```
Tbl1 (tbl1_id PK)
-----
1
2

Tbl2 (tbl2_id PK, tbl1_id)
-----
1
2
3
```

if you tried to create the foreign key, it would face as 3 does not exist within your primary table.

So yes, they are equivalent, just note that SQL server has built in safe guards to protect against invalid relational data.

Comment: Thanks, I did not have the courage to experiment with this on a foreign database, nor the time to create an own database and fill it with data to experiment with. I agree that inconsistencies are the task of the programmer to deal with, but I wonder whether indexes will be automatically added to increase performance or not as well. I will accept your answer anyway, as it is a straightforward and clear one.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/836176/2312877 , for sql server indexes are not automatically created for foreign keys

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense.