# Foreign key and index

Tags: sql, laravel, indexing, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there any difference between

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

and

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

For me it's the same because foreign key is an index, am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer:

Some databases by default put indexes on all created foreign keys automatically.

Eloquent only does a - create foreign key - command for and MySQL automatically adds the index.

Thanks to Mittensoff from laracasts for the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836167/does-a-foreign-key-automatically-create-an-index), it's good to index a foreign key, but database won't index it automatically.

So 2 code blocks above are different.

I think you can try to open your database schema and check for it.

Comment: When I create a foreign key without any index, I see in my database that the foreign key is an index, that why I ask this question. I don't know exactly what is eloquent's behavior.