# How can I ask Hibernate to create an index on a foreign key (JoinColumn)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, indexing, foreign-keys

Here is my model:

```java
class User {

    @CollectionOfElements 
    @JoinTable(name = "user_type", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    private List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

As you can imagine there would be a table called "user_type", which has two columns, one is "user_id" and the other is "type".

When I use *hbm2ddl* to generate the ddls, I want to have this table, along with the foreign key constraint on "user_id".
However, there is no index for this column. How can I get *hibernate* to generate the index for me?

Comment: What is your database/dialect? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

Try an @Index annotation.

```
@Index(name="user_type_index")
```

There is also an @IndexColumn annotation used with join tables, but it doesn't seem to actually create an index, but controls which field defines order in list semantics.

The @Index column in this context does seem to create an index on the join table.

Comment: Yes.  It worked for me.  Could be database-dependent I suppose.

Comment: Related: issues with `@Index` and `@ManyToMany`, labeled "won't fix" as there is a workaround in hibernate 4.3+ https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4263

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with a similar issue and I've found that some dialects will automatically index foreign keys and others wont.

Hibernate [Dialect](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.1.GA/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.java#Dialect.getAddForeignKeyConstraintString%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cboolean%29) class and all subclasses which do not override the getAddForeignKeyConstraintString method (Oracle, SQL Server, etc) will not create an index on the foreign key.

[MySQLDialect](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.1.GA/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java#MySQLDialect.getAddForeignKeyConstraintString%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cboolean%29) overrides that method and adds an index to every foreign key

Comment: I pulled the sources today, and cannot confirm this - the method is overridden by MySQL dialect, but there seems to be no code to add an index https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java

Comment: Instead, MySQL seems to add indices automatically if you use the InnoDB dialect, according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/1145183/1143126

Comment: _If neither a CONSTRAINT symbol or FOREIGN KEY index_name is defined, the foreign key index name is generated using the name of the referencing foreign key column._ [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)