# Why the index was automatically created to foreign key fields?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I create the foreign key to one field in my table, the index was automatically created to that field. why the index was automatically created to foreign key fields?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304317/does-mysql-index-foreign-key-columns-automatically

Comment: Because indexes are automatically created for columns that act as foreign keys. Check MySQL manual.

Comment: Not a dupe, the linked question asks: does MySQL put an index on foreign keys (answer yes), this question aks: Why?

Comment: in the answers the people answer why look at Mr Alexander

Answer (score 1):

The indices are created on foreign keys to improve performance. If you have a foreign key is common to want to get related items, an index allows you to quickly get these items. Also the conditions imposed on foreign keys (delete, update) take advantage of the index to work fast. Finally you need to perform integrity checks when creating foreign keys, this requires performing searches, these searches take advantage of the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Key fields link to the contents of fields in other tables.

If we create a table like so:

```
Table Patient
  id 
  name
  address
```

And a table Illness

```
Table Illness
  id
  patient_id foreign key to patient.id
  description
```

MySQL checks to see if a foreign link to table `patient` actually matches up with the id in `Illness`. It also does the reverve, if a `patient` is deleted, it checks to make sure it is not referenced in `illness`.
In order to do this effiently it needs to index these fields, otherwise it will have to do a spend too much time doing full table lookups.

Besides, the word `key` is a synonym for `index` so it makes sense to index keys :-).

Comment: k..Then how can i create foreign keys without create index?

Comment: @Sunitha, that's impossible why would you want to do a thing like that?

Comment: Like Johan said, "In order to do this efficiently it needs to index these fields, otherwise it will have to do a spend too much time doing full table lookups."