# MySQL index performance… index on WHERE depending on status

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

The table contains 4 columns: id (autoincrement), userid (unique, like ssn), status (TINYINT(1), 0 or 1 values, not NULL), user_info (varchar(1000)).

Should I put index on userid column to increase performance, if:
30% of requests is

```
"SELECT user_info from Table1 WHERE userid='1234567'";
```

40% of requests is:

```
"SELECT user_info from Table1 WHERE userid='1234567' AND status=0";
```

20% of requests is:

```
"SELECT user_info from Table1 WHERE userid='1234567' AND status=1";
```

Or, there is a better way to increase the performance (I should think about indexing of status column somehow)?

Should I change something if instead of (30%,40%,20%) it will actually become (9%,90%,1%), i.e. most requests are for status=0?
Thank you.

Comment: A table name like "userid" implies that column is a foreign key (to the User table, id field.)

If you defined it as a foreign key on an InnoDB table, it's automatically indexed.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304317/does-mysql-index-foreign-key-columns-automatically

Good info about indexing fk's:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:292016138754

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index on `status` is very unlikely to increase the SELECT performance as the column content is not diverse enough. An index on `userid` is very likely to increase performance a lot as the column content is very diverse.

When you've defined the `userid` column as `unique` the automatically created unique index should already be used in your queries. So there's no need to define an additional index.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest delete id column (synthetic key - what is it for?). Than, make a cumulative PK of user_id (first) and status (second).

Even better solution - remove status from PK and select always by user_id only. Check status in application and throw 404 or whatever.