# I am unable to drop a foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to drop a foriegn key in php admin (mysql) so I am performing this code below:

```
`ALTER TABLE Image_Question DROP INDEX FK_QuestionSession`
```

Problem is though that I am receiving this error:

```
#1553 - Cannot drop index 'FK_QuestionSession': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

The foreign key for QuestionId is linked from the Image_Question Table to the QuestionId in the Question Table.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Cannot drop index needed in a foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482346/mysql-cannot-drop-index-needed-in-a-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove foreign key constrain first and then drop index. Otherwise you will always get error.

```
alter table Image_Question drop foreign key key_name_here
```

Comment: Thanks I will accept answer when it lets me in couple of mins