# Asp.Net Core Entity Framework Migration Error: index needed in a foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Pomelo Entity Franework Core MySql Provider and I have scaffolded a migration, that drops an index in a MySql database. It looks  this

```
public partial class IndexUpdate : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Buildings_AddressId",
            table: "Buildings");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Buildings_AddressId",
            table: "Buildings",
            column: "AddressId",
            unique: true);
    }
}
```

The database contains this index and it has a type of UNIQUE. When I conduct the migration an error occurs with the following message:

Cannot drop index 'IX_Buildings_AddressId': needed in a foreign key constraint

I fully understand that it is a basic sql drop index operation, I have found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482346/mysql-cannot-drop-index-needed-in-a-foreign-key-constraint). My question is: is there a way not to drop and create a foreign key in order to drop index? I would prefer to resolve the problem in terms of Entity Framework/MySql provider rather than raw Sql

Comment: Check some of the less upvoted answers from the linked SO question and you will find your answer :) Recap: create another index that can be used by the FK and then drop the index you want.

Comment: @Shadow I would like to resolve the issue using .net rather than sql

Comment: Then create another index from asp.net before dropping the one in the question.