# Grails Database Migration Plugin Issues

Tags: mysql, grails, plugins, database-migration

When I use the [Grails Database Migration Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) and run a `dbm-gorm-diff` (for example, after installing the Spring Security Facebook plugin) I have been getting problems like:

```
Error: Error executing SQL CREATE INDEX `FK609FD5A460CFCC39` ON `facebook_user`(`user_id`): Incorrect index name 'FK609FD5A460CFCC39'
```

It looks like the index in question is both a FK constraint and is then reused as an index later in the generated upgrade script. If i change the name, thus removing the duplicate, everything works fine. I am using Mysql. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you been using the plugin successfully up till now?

Comment: @David It is still pretty new to me. I tried a few basic upgrades and they worked.

Comment: I was just thinking if maybe you have `dbcreate="..something.."` in your DataSource.groovy file it might be conflicting with the plugin. But if you've done upgrades already that seems to be less likely.

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve that issue? I have the exact same issue right now and I can't figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found out that if I edit changelog.groovy to place addForeignConstraint's after createIndex's, it works like a charm. Yet another problem in the changelog generation script I guess.

Comment: Strange, this solution didn't work for me.  I had multiple `addForeignConstraint`s and multiple `createIndex`s.  Changing the key did allow it to work though... don't know if that will have any adverse effects later.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is actually related to MySQL and not to the plugin itself. See this bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55465

Sebastien's answer is a work around.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304317/does-mysql-index-foreign-key-columns-automatically), MYSQL automatically indexes foreign key columns.  So when you add a foreign key constraint, you don't need to also define an index.  I use the db migration plugin and just remove the 'index' entries for foreign keys that the dbm-gorm-diff generates.

I think this is a bit better than changing the name, since that likely creates more than one index on the same column which is just a waste of resources.