# Temporary table sending large result set (What is worse temp table or sending huge result set)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a [temporary table that could send large result sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178038/expensive-query-takes-down-database-server-looking-for-ways-to-mitigate). Is it more expensive to send large result sets OR the actual creation of the table. (10,000+ row result sets)

My server got overloaded and a lot of the queries in the process list said either

- "Sending data"
- "Copying to tmp table"

I have added LIMIT and OFFSET for the query against the temporary table, so that should help the sending data part.

What is worse...The creation of a temporary table that is an expensive query....or sending the whole entire temporary table in a simple select? (They both seem pretty bad)

Comment: Send results sets where?  This question is very vague, so I voted to close it.

Comment: Why not cache the data in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decent server can easily handle 10k records - most times, the network is the bigger issue when sending a lot of data back and forth.  Network traffic is usually more important, and you'll have the network support team coming after you if you're using all their bandwidth!