# Will I see performance gains by creating table relationships?

Tags: mysql, performance

I understand the benefits of using table relationships in order to create constraints, such as preventing a row from being deleted from one table when it is related to a row in another.

But will doing so improve performance when running joined queries.

Eg. suppose I have InnoDB tables USER and USERINFO as shown below:

```
    USER
   |Field   |Type        |Null  |Key    |Default          |Extra
 --|id      |int(11)     |NO    |PRI    |                 |auto_increment
|  |email   |varchar(700)|NO    |       |                 |
|  |password|varchar(255)|NO    |       |                 |
|  |active  |varchar(1)  |NO    |       |n                |
|  |created |timestamp   |NO    |       |CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|
|
|   USERINFO
|  |Field   |Type        |Null  |Key    |Default          |Extra
 --|user    |int(11)     |NO    |PRI    |                 |
   |name    |varchar(100)|NO    |       |                 |
   |position|varchar(100)|NO    |       |                 |
    ...
```

Is it beneficial in terms of performance when running the following query?

```
SELECT * FROM USER U JOIN USERINFO UI ON U.id = UI.user
```

Comment: No. *constraint* itself is nothing more than a constraint code, the real work of "improvement" is done by *index* which you will have to create in order to introduce your constraint. So, if you already have your indixes, then your constraint will not improve your performance (on the opposite - it will a little bit slow you down because of check costs). If you don't have index, then a gain will came from creating *index*, not *constraint*

Comment: Good comment @AlmaDo. When we factor in data less likely to screw up, real performance goes thru the roof

Answer (score 2):

It's an index that *might* (and most likely *will*) boost performance, not a foreign key alone.

Also: [MySQL creates foreign key indexes automatically for InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304317/does-mysql-index-foreign-key-columns-automatically).