# Should I use FOREIGN KEY or ADD INDEX in sql?

Tags: mysql

Today I have seen a video lecture in which they gave the `foriegn key` by using `ADD INDEX` on a table -

#### CASE 1 -

DECRIPTION OF TABLE 1 : **subjects**

```
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| menu_name | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position  | int(3)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| visible   | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

DECRIPTION OF TABLE 2 : **pages**

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subject_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| menu_name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position   | int(3)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| visible    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| content    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So in the column `subject_id` of table `pages` should store the `id` of table `subjects`.
Which one should i use and why ? -
**ALTER TABLE pages ADD INDEX fk_subject_id (subject_id);**
OR
**ALTER TABLE pages
ADD FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES students(id)**;

video lecture uses `ALTER TABLE pages ADD INDEX fk_subject_id (subject_id);`.

---

#### CASE 2 -

Now Please cosider one more example -
According to above details, If I have 5 more tables including `pages` table(defined above).
All 5 tables have column `subject_id` which should store the data accodring to column `id` of table `subjects`.

So in this case 
In this case, Which one Should I use `ADD INDEX` or `FOREIGN KEY` and why ?

Comment: Index and foreign key are two different things.

Comment: @emix I gave the case 1 because video lecture are not using `FORIEGN KEY`.

Comment: @emix They are adding `subject_id` from column `id` of table subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Q : case 1 - Which one should i use ?
A : I'll choose `fk not index`,because the reference between pages and subjects is `multi to one`,if you add index on column with `duplicate` values that would not be helpful,because in most cases, only one index can be used to optimize a database query,and there's a `primary index` on subjects,so don't do that again.

note : you have to make pages - subject_id `not null`

Q : case 2 - Which one should i use ?
A : if the `5 tables` between subjects are also `multi to one`,i'll choose `FK not index`,the reason like case1's answer.

Comment: Please tell me the answer with why should i use this ?

Comment: If the question is if `use ADD INDEX or FOREIGN KEY` (**or**) how can the answer be `yes`?

Comment: Please read my question again and tell me the answer for both cases including why

Comment: @wei complete your answer by adding case 2's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `FOREIGN KEY` and an `INDEX` are different things. `FOREIGN KEYs` are used for data integrity, so that you cannot have a reference, which points to nothing and that you cannot delete the "base" row without deleting the "linking" rows first (unless you use `ON CASCADE DELETE` stuff).

Indices are used to improve the search speed to find the correct rows faster in an `SELECT` and `UPDATE` query. This has nothing to do with data integrity.

To answer your question: You use a `FOREIGN KEY` if you want to reference the Id of rows from the other table (like you do with `subject_id`). Also, you don't need to add an `INDEX` on the column `subject_id`, because the [InnoDB engine already does that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304317/does-mysql-index-foreign-key-columns-automatically/304339#304339).

Comment: ok thanks then also tell me how can i use both `ADD INDEX` and `FOREIGN KEY` to get fast search and data integrity respectively ?

Comment: @Abhishekkamal As I already wrote it, you don't need to, the [InnoDB engine already does that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304317/does-mysql-index-foreign-key-columns-automatically/304339#304339).

Comment: you got me wrong... I am not asking to add `INDEX` only on the column `subject_id`, it can be any column.

Comment: @Abhishekkamal You can add an INDEX on almost any column type you want. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html on how to add an index to one or more columns of your table.