# What does the tag <link rel="icon" href="data:,"> do?

Tags: html

I have seen this tag several times but can't find a simple explanation that is understood by us "non-professionals".

Comment: You are looking at a [favicon tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304317/does-mysql-index-foreign-key-columns-automatically) that's how you set the little icon in the address bar.

Answer (score 5):

the tag  returns an empty image without requesting the server.

you use it for speed reason: you avoid 1 server request, 1 data transfer, 1 layout/render browser calculation. For example, I have a one static HTML, which size is 10ko including only 1 server request. My site icon is 9ko. and I don't want to multiply by 2 the request et the transfer size.

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link):

> The rel stands for "relationship", and is probably one of the key
>   features of the  element — the value denotes how the item being
>   linked to is related to the containing document. As you'll see from
>   our Link types reference, there are many different kinds of
>   relationship.

From your question, the `data` is likely pointing to a base64 encoded value which will render as the favicon for the website. You can base64 encode values for other elements as well, such as in this example:

```html
<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7">
```

## What is `href='data:` ?

Well, `href` is a hypertext reference. Typically, you'll see the value of `href` pointing to a path to a file or link, such as:

```html
<a href="some-page.html">
```

But it can point to an encoded image. The way you represent an encoded image is with `data`. So we're asking the browser to associate the `href` with an image we're creating inside `data:`.

## Example Icon Structure

Here is a sample structure you can follow for base64 encoding an icon. As @agrm pointed out a comment, you'll need to specify the `mediatype` as well.

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAAAAAAAABoBQAAF/QA6OjoAKysrABwcH" />
```

Comment: Yes I have seen favicon.ico line such as:

Comment: @Rhino Does my answer provide a solution for you? If so, please accept it :)

Comment: Oops hit enter too early. I have seen favicon.ico lines  such as : <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >  but please bare with me and explain the       
 " href='data:," part.....

Comment: The data url format is `data:<mediatype>,<data>`. The icon you have seen (`data:,`) has no media type or data given, which means it will be an empty icon.

Comment: Ok, so the line <link rel="icon"  href="data:,"> does not do anything on its own ?? (it needs a  base64 encoded data sring to actually show a favicon) ?? (The program line  comes from cut n' paste  of  another html program, thats why I don't know how it works ). So if i manage to produce a  base64-encoded favicon code string, should this string be placed right after the "data:" part of the line ??

Comment: Oh you are really fast in answering my questions.  During the time I am  struggling in writing the questions, you have already sent me the answers....  Thank you all for being so helpful !!!!

Comment: @Rhino I added a more complete example you can follow, which contains a `mediatype`. Please accept my solution if you're happy with it.

Comment: I've just added my first (working) base64-encoded favicon to my project thanks to you guys. I wrote my question, went for a cup of coffee, and when I came back the answers were already there, stackoverflow seems like a fantastic forum. Thank you all...

Comment: @Rhino Just curious why you removed my answer as the selected solution.

Comment: Hmm, as far as I know I have not removed anything. My problem is that i'm new to stack owerflow, so i might have done something by mistake, (definitely not deliberately). As I mentioned earlier i am very grateful for all the help I got from you, You wanted me to accept your solution, which i thought i did by clicking  the green arrow ?? Please advise if this is the wrong way of accepting....

Comment: @Rhino Clicking the upward facing arrow will upvote the answer, but clicking the check mark beneath the downward facing arrow selects the answer as the solution.